# Page and content localization

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

When I am using html with page-localize.js, jquery.localize.js , jquery.extensions.js. and I edit the content of html, the data is not getting reflected in the output. It is showing the old text. If I remove the header link to these localize files, the page is loading the new content. What is the use of these files? coz when I add the link, again it shows the old content even if the content is nowhere on the html... What kind of bug / security is this? How is it restoring old content after deleting it completely?

Comment: delete the cookies, localStorage values etc. and see if that works.

Comment: I copied the newly edited files on a different pc. Still i am facing the same problem

Comment: I have no clue absolutely as to how is it generating data that i have deleted from the html tags